# Proof of pointwise convergence of derivative of power series

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, power-series

I proved:

If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges for all $x \in (-R,R)$ then the differentiated series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n x^{n-1}$ converges for all $x \in (-R,R)$.

Please could somebody tell me if my proof is correct?

Let $x \in (-R,R)$  and $t$ be any $t$ such that $|x|<t<R$. Then (ratio test):

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left | { a_{n+1} x^{n+1 }\over a_n x^n} \right | = \lim \left | { a_{n+1} {x^{n+1} \over t^{n+1}} t^{n+1}\over a_n {x^n\over t^n} t^n} \right | = \lim \left | { a_{n+1}  t^{n+1}\over a_n  t^n} \right | \left | {{x^{n+1} \over t^{n+1}} \over {x^n\over t^n}} \right | = K \left | {x \over t} \right |$$

where $K < 1$ because $\sum a_n x^n$ converges and $|{x \over t}| < 1$ because $t > x$. Therefore $ K \left | {x \over t} \right |<1$ and by the ratio test the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n x^{n-1}$  converges.

Comment: This doesn't quite work -- it is possible for a series to be convergent but get exactly $1$ out of the ratio test.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson Thank you for your comment. In that case it would still work, no? I could replace $K <1$ with $K \le 1$ and the product $K (x/t)$ would still be less than $1$ because $x/t$ is?

Comment: Another problem is that $a_n$ may be $0$ for infinitely many $n$. But the idea with the $t$ is the right one. Since $\sum a_n t^n$ converges, we know there is a $C$ such that $\lvert a_n\rvert t^n \leqslant C$. Then $\lvert n a_n x^{n-1}\rvert \leqslant C t^{-1} n \left(\frac{\lvert x\rvert}{t}\right)^{n-1}$, and the latter converges by comparison with the derived geometric series.